# How to share files via a shared drive across multiple VM's running Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, filesystem, shared-folders

I am trying to share a single disk across multiple VM's. The VM's are hosted in Azure and the disk is an Azure Managed Disk. I've attached the disk to both VM's and have mounted them. I can see the partition on each, as well as the test file I've created, `test.txt`. However, updates to the contents of the txt file while SSH'ed into VM1 are not reflected in VM22. Instead, the VM2 shows the prior value until I unmount and remount the drive.

I'm new to Ubuntu/Linux, and am trying to figure out where to look. My initial thoughts...

1. Perhaps the filesystem I'm using (`gpt`) cannot support multiple, concurrent access in this manner and I must use something else? If so, what is more suitable?
2. The VM seems to take a copy of the file when it's mounted and writes are not shared. Perhaps this is the problem and this can be turned off?
3. Perhaps this is a problem with Azure, although I no longer believe it to be.
4. Perhaps there is a permissions issue because the user accounts differ between machines. I know Linux includes permissions on a file + directory basis as a first-class concern.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: This is very much an Azure issue, please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-shared#linux Multiple machines can not have write access to the drive at once unless you set extra things up.

Comment: @Esther thank you, let me read up on that link. for my use case, i actually only need one machine to be able to write. all others just need to be able to read, but that seems to be a problem too.